# Getting all profile pictures using Microsoft Graph in C#

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am creating an application in .NET Core 6, where I need to get all profile pictures of users in my org, using the Microsoft Graph SDK.
The application is using an app-only token.

First I have tried to do this, and only get one picture, using the users ID:

```
public static async Task<Task<ProfilePhoto?>> GetUsersPhotos(string id)
        {
            // Ensure client isn't null
            _ = _appClient ??
                throw new NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for app-only auth");
            try
            {
                var requestUserPhoto = _appClient.Users[id].Photo.GetAsync();
                return requestUserPhoto;
            }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + odataError.Error.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This returns an OData error, which it seems I am not able to inspect. I have no problems getting other data using the SDK. I have only been able to find getting the signed in users profile picture, in the Microsoft documentation.

The end result should be a FileStream or some other format which I can save as a JPG on a server.

Comment: Could you check whether the app has granted User.Read.All application permission?

Comment: Yes, it has. I can also make a GetUsers e.g., so that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly return the stream through [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-get-the-photo-for-the-signed-in-user-in-the-largest-available-size) request builder

```
public static async Task<Stream> GetUsersPhotos(string id)
    {
        // Ensure client isn't null
        _ = _appClient ??
            throw new NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for app-only auth");
        try
        {
            return await _appClient.Users[id].Photo.Content.GetAsync();
        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + odataError.Error.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And save the content to a file

```
using (var stream = await GetUsersPhotos(user.Id))
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: That still gives me an OData error. I have the User.Read.All permissions set up, so it probably isn't that. EDIT: Ah, it was of course because the user I tested it on, didn't have a picture. This was the solution, many thanks!!